# Who is it? ( Asking about a person)

Tags: word-choice

When can I use "it" when talking about people in questions and not only in questions? The correct word is "this" "that"  in the question "Who is this?" "It" is used in an answer. As in "it's my friend Anna. But aren't there contexts in which I can use "it" in questions or statements or negative sentences when talking about people?

Comment: If you are asking the identity of an unseen person, for example someone who knocks at your door late at night when you are wary about opening it, you might call out "Who is it?"

Comment: In your examples, the "neuter pronoun" ***it*** isn't really being used to refer to a person - it's more like the pronoun ***it*** after the hyphen in this very sentence (which is the "existential ***it***" referring to "the situation in general", rather than being a pronoun referring to the word "it" itself). Consider "Knock, knock", "Who is **it**?", "**It's** Jane", where ***it*** doesn't directly refer to "Jane" - in both cases it's really just a general-purpose reference, similar to ***It's** raining*.

Comment: Do you mean "it's Jane", Jane is responding?